# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twitter'

Tags: python, python-3.x, twitter

I am attempting to import a twitter api wrapper. I am using https://github.com/bear/python-twitter and have installed it using `pip install python-twitter`, when I run `pip freeze` into the command prompt it shows that I have `python-twitter==3.2.1` installed however when I try to import it using `import twitter` in Jupyter QTConsole running Python 3.6.0, I get back this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-1-645f6dc1896f> in <module>()
----> 1 import twitter

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'twitter'
```

I am at a loss as to what is going wrong, the package doesn't say it's restricted to a certain version of python, and searching online hasn't helped. So now I am asking here in case anyone has a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I had 2 versions of Anaconda installed and the package was defaulting to the wrong one, uninstalling the older version of anaconda and reinstalling the package fixed the problem.

Comment: This solution is not broadly applicable... :\